# Force .NET GC to compact or defragment generation 2 heap?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, defragmentation, heap-fragmentation

We wrote a windows service by C# in .NET framework, after some hours we noticed that the size of heap generation 2 is growing unordinary. 
Most of this space is free and dotMemory Profiler showed us that we have about 90% fragmentations on this generation.
How can I enforce .NET GC to compact this space? It means that GC could free this space but It couldn't compact it for further usage.

Comment: afaik GC defrags it automatically when you try to allocate new memory and it realizes that there is no more big enough chunk. Unless you get a real problem with that (e.g. the defrag taking too much time when it finally happens), you shouldn't take care of this yourself.

Comment: You'll have to dig deeper.  This happens when objects in your program are pinned for a very long time.  Or if the finalizer thread is deadlocked.

Comment: @RenéVogt I got a real problem with this unusual growing size! so I decided to handle it myself. I saw about 2G generation 2 Heap but only about 30M is used and the rest of that is fragmented and free.

Comment: What version of .net framework - GC has changed in 4.5

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5.1

Comment: Was this issue ever resolved?

Comment: Our windows service had memory leakage and by disposing these buffers, we handled the problem. so, we didn't need any other defragmentation.

Answer (score 1):

Since generation 0,1,2 will compact and delete by GC it's self,

Guess that object allocate on Large object heap(LOH, Object size >= 85K)

So, you can try LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode, it can compact loh

```
GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
GC.Collect();
```

Ref : [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Generation 2 heap is small object heap, so basically gen 2 will compact too(Since we call GC.Collect())

And Large Object Heap(>=85K) won't compact automatically.
I want to compact LOH, you can use .Net Framework.

So have make sure which heap you used~